# If there are no prey conditions, does an enemy get assigned to whomever the lead investigator wishes?

Tags: arkham-horror-card-game

If I draw a monster that does not have prey instructions, and I have both my investigator and the lead investigator at my location, is it the lead investigator's choice who gets engaged with it?  The rules don't explicitly say under Enemy Engagement in the Rules Reference (page 10):

> If there are multiple investigators at the same location as a ready unengaged enemy, follow the enemy’s prey instructions to determine which investigator is engaged.

Then under Prey on page 17:

> If an enemy that is about to automatically engage an investigator at its location has multiple options of whom to engage, that enemy engages the investigator who best meets its “prey” instructions (if multiple investigators are tied in meeting these instructions, the lead investigator may decide among them)

So, while a card might not actually **have** a Prey section, can we take this to mean that such cards will be up to the lead investigator to place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Close. If you *draw* an enemy (e.g., from the mythos encounter deck or your own deck), then prey instructions are always ignored -- the monster automatically engages whichever investigator drew the card.  The lead investigator has no say in the matter.

However, if there are two investigators at a location, and an enemy *moves into* that location (e.g., from the hunter keyword) *and* has no prey instructions, then the lead investigator can choose who the monster engages with.

In the RRG, this is covered under the event details for the Mythos phase:

> If the card is an enemy, spawn it following any spawn instruction the
>   card bears. (A spawn instruction is any text bearing a "spawn"
>   precursor.) If the encountered enemy has no spawn instruction, the
>   enemy spawns **engaged with the investigator encountering the card** and
>   is placed in that investigator's threat area.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that Spawn instructions override normal "engaged with whoever drew it" outcome, and in that case Prey and/or investigator's choice will apply. E.g. even if you and another investigator are both in the Attic and you draw monster that has "Spawn - Attic", you follow Prey instructions or lead investigator's choice instead of automatically having it engaged with you.